# Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write Regex in C#, I write the following code:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("n>");
string str = "burn";
int x=0;
if(reg.IsMatch(str))
  x++;
```

But, always x equals zero. does anyone know why?

Thanks,
Rachel

Comment: See answer below, but can you tell us what you are trying to match? an "n" at the end of a string maybe?

Answer (score 5):

You mean to match a word boundary by `>`, but these are expressed by `\b` in .NET regex:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("n\\b");  // alternatively: Regex(@"n\b");
```

Comment: What kind of regex notation is `>`?

Comment: @splash: Some engines, like the one in vi/vim use the pointy brackets to denote word boundaries. It's more expressive than `\b`, because you can differentiate start-of-word `<` and end-of-word `>`.

Comment: Ah... the penny drops. Had no idea > was word boundary in other regex implementations.

Comment: In the help of visual studio write that "> maches only when aword ends at this point in the text". the path in the help:"ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/MS.msdnqtr.v90.en/dv_vsnav/html/718a617d-0e05-47e1-a218-9746971527f4.htm"

Comment: @Jamiec: `<` and `>` are word boundaries in Visual Studio **only**.  In flavors that conform to the GNU ERE standard, like `grep` and `sed`, the bracket is preceded by a backslash: `\<`, `\>`.

Comment: @Alan: That makes me wonder why Visual Studio uses a different implementation of regex than .NET, as this makes no sense *at all* to me.

Comment: @Tomalak:  These posts by Paul Dempsey constitute the best explanation I've found: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/regexp/thread/110ad401-7c0d-42e4-8776-84c825a68645/#db5e2130-9102-41ec-978e-567f2f93b9af and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/b1b4e320-c0ff-4dc8-884d-29239950c78f/#9307dfef-22b2-46a5-84ae-792dfe98e7fe

Comment: @Alan: Great explanation, thanks for digging that up! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

> But, always x equals zero. does anyone know why?

Because the regular expression "n>" does not match the string "burn".

Comment: It was an indulgant answer. I was trying not to be too facaecious. :D

Comment: But it is also not really an answer. Every question "Why does this not work?" could be answered with "Because you are doing it wrong."; but no problem could be *solved* that way. ;-)

Comment: In the help of visual stdio write:" > matches only when aword ends at this point in the text. For example: SS>matches words such as 'across' and 'loss' tat end with the letters 'ss'",

Comment: The path in the help:ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/MS.msdnqtr.v90.en/dv_vsnav/html/718a617d-0e05-47e1-a218-9746971527f4.htm

Comment: @Rachel, It's Visual Stdio regular expression for find and replace in IDE which is differ with .Net regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong part of the help. That help is for Visual Studio's Find and Replace dialogs. Some of the syntax from help is not valid for use in C# (or rather does not have the same effect). So if you had a word "burn" in your code and you entered `n>` into find box and tried searching you would've found n in burn - see the picture:

[image: Screenshot]

You probably need to use `n\b` as Tomalak pointed out.

See more details from MSDN: [Regular Expression Language Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, but what does replase "<", that uses to match only when a word starts at this point?

Comment: \b again, but you'd use \bb for burn - this will check if b is a the beginning of the word. Something like: Regex reg = new Regex(@"n\b");
            string str = "burn";
            int x = 0;
            if (reg.IsMatch(str))
                x++;

            Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"\bb");

            if (reg2.IsMatch(str))
                x++;